# Why do these SQLite queries return different results?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Background:  I'm brand new to SQL, and working on [this homework assignment](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment2/assignment2.html) for a Coursera course.  [Data file here](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment2/reuters.db).  The database contains a single table `frequency(docid, term, count)`.

Actual question:  Why do the following two SQLite queries return different results?
(1)

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM(
        SELECT term
        FROM frequency
        WHERE docid = '10398_txt_earn' AND count=1
    UNION
        SELECT term
        FROM frequency
        WHERE docid = '925_txt_trade' AND count=1);
```

returns

```
coun
----
324
```

(2)

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM frequency
WHERE (docid = '10398_txt_earn' OR docid = '925_txt_trade') AND count = 1;
```

returns

```
coun
----
335
```

Comment: I flagged it, it belongs to StackOverflow.

Comment: Try `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT term` in the first example.

Comment: What do you see if you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query gives 325

```
SELECT count(term)
FROM(
        SELECT term
        FROM frequency
        WHERE docid = '10398_txt_earn' AND count=1
          UNION ALL
        SELECT term
        FROM frequency
        WHERE docid = '925_txt_trade' AND count=1
);
```

The problem is that UNION merges duplicate results so the following query

```
SELECT A.TERM
FROM (
  SELECT term
  FROM frequency
  WHERE docid = '10398_txt_earn' AND count=1
) A
JOIN (    
  SELECT term
  FROM frequency
  WHERE docid = '925_txt_trade' AND count=1
) B ON A.term = B.term;
```

Will show you the items that are in both (11 of them)

```
based
costs
export
july
many
march
month
problems
reuter
speech
world
```

This query will also give the same results:

```
SELECT term
FROM frequency
WHERE docid = '10398_txt_earn' AND count=1
INTERSECT
SELECT term
FROM frequency
WHERE docid = '925_txt_trade' AND count=1;
```